# Insert Text with Python Selenium. .send_keys() doesn´t work

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, text

In my code I extract some text from a txt-file. I unterstood that readlines() gives me a list of the seperate lines in the text. I want to convert this list to one string. I do it with my_text = "".join(list).
Now i want to put this text in a website. I open the website with selenium und try to enter the text with
driver.send_key(my_text).
And here it starts acting weird.
If I past a simple String like "Hello World" as an argument (driver.send_keys("Hello World")) it works.
It even works if I put this simple text in my file and let the program read it. Just when my file contains the larger text it´s weird.
If I try to paste "my_text" it starts to click all the links below the textbox on the website.

```
file = open(location_text)
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

my_text = "".join(lines)
driver = webdriver.Edge(r"C:\Users\felix\PycharmProjects\testSkrip\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://wip-duisburg.de/kontakt/")
text_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wpcf7-f3716-p1806-o1"]/form/p[6]/label/span/textarea')
text_box.send_keys(my_text)
```

It seems like the text in my file interacts with the website. I really can´t solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Strip and join with `\n`:

```
my_text = "\n".join([x.strip() for x in lines])
```

Comment: Could you explain what it does?

Comment: It strips the text